# Is point texture filtering the same as nearest?

Tags: textures, filtering

Is point texture filtering the same as nearest (different names for the same technique)?

Comment: What's the context for this?

Comment: What do you mean by context? I found this in Unity editor when importing textures and specifiyng filtering (point, linear, anisotropic).

Comment: That's what I meant. :D I was just curious what prompted the question. Have you tried it? Does the result look like what you'd expect from nearest-pixel?

Comment: E-e, no, didn't try yet. I thought it was easier to ask someone who knows. Anyway, going to use linear filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are different names for the same thing.